# Нужны ли тут запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

Постоянно путаюсь. Известно, что перед "как" в значении "в качестве" запятая не ставится. А как быть, например, с таким предложением: "Я(,) как порядочный человек(,) в данной ситуации не могу молчать"? Тут ведь тоже "как" в значении "в качестве".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здесь значение причины. НЕ могу молчать, так как я порядочный человек. В таком случае оборот с как обособляется.